# mySQL world DB Monarchy

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an assignment where I need to use the world DB in mySQL to find the 5 largest cities and their countries in countries where the government form is any type of monarchy.  I am trying it with the distinct clause, and the only info that appears correct is the government column.  Everything else is for India.  Does anyone have an idea?

```
select distinct city.name, governmentform, city.population, countrycode
from country, city
where governmentform like='%monarchy%'
order by city.population desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: You need a link between city and country. Does the `city` table as a `id_country` field or something like this? Then you would need to JOIN instead of selection 2 tables. Also instead of distinct, I think in that case you should use GROUP BY(city.name)

Comment: Yes it does, so then I am getting rid of the distinct, and I am adding an and statement to where that reads and city.countrycode=country.code.  I think that is working, thanks a bunch!!